# How to Find Out What Headers Are in a DLL or LIB?

Tags: dll

Is there a way to find out what header files are used in a DLL or LIB?

More specifically, I need to remove rpcrt4 from a project that, instead of using the rpcrt4.dll, is using the headers that are used in rpcrt4. I need to figure out which header files are from rpcrt4 so I know which header files to remove from the project.

Comment: The header files (`.h`) are not necessarily related to libraries. It's  mostly a convention. The libraries contain no trace of header files.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, you cannot know which exact header file was used when a library was compiled. Usualy the library is published with a matching header though (which is often the same it was compiled with).